# Successfully created a tokbox project, using python and urllib2, however I cannot create S3-archive

Tags: python, amazon-s3, urllib2, opentok, tokbox

Using python/urllib2 I've successfully created a tokbox/opentok project.
However I am unable to create the much-needed S3-archive. When attempted to get the S3-part working, I'm receiving the following:

403, Forbidden
{"code":-1,"message":"Invalid token","description":"Invalid token"}

I'm using jwt.encode to create the needed token, using ist:account.
Though for the S3 portion, I also tried ist:project.
When using the put-call, I've tried the original token, used for creating the original project, as well as a newly created token, (both account or project)...but I still see the "Invalid token" message.

```
token = jwt.encode({"iss": "*******",                                           
    "iat": int(time.time()),                                                      
    "exp": int(time.time()) + 180,                                                
    "ist": "account",                                                             
    "jti": str(uuid.uuid4())},                                                    
    '***************************************',                                    
    algorithm='HS256')                                                            
                                                                                  url = 'https://api.opentok.com/v2/project'                                      

headers = { "X-OPENTOK-AUTH": token }                                           
values = {'name' : 'MyTestproject' }                                            
data = json.dumps(values)                                                       

req = urllib2.Request(url, data, { 'X-OPENTOK-AUTH': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
try:                                                                               
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)                                                       
except urllib2.URLError as e:                                                              
    print e.reason                                                                 
    print e.code                                                                   
    print e.read()                                                                 
    sys.exit()                                                                     

jsondump = json.loads(f.read())                                                    
api_key =  jsondump['apiKey']                                                      

s3_token = jwt.encode({"iss": "*******",                                           
    "iat": int(time.time()),                                                         
    "exp": int(time.time()) + 180,                                                   
    "ist": "account",                                                                
    "jti": str(uuid.uuid4())},                                                       
    '***************************************',                                       
    algorithm='HS256')                                                               

s3_data = json.dumps( {                                                            
             "type": "s3",                                                           
             "config": {                                                             
             "accessKey":s3_access_key,                                           
             "secretKey":s3_secret_key,                                           
             "bucket": s3_prod_bucket                                             
          },                                                                       
          "fallback":"opentok"                                                     
  })                                                                                 


s3_url = 'https://api.opentok.com/v2/project/'+ api_key + '/archive/storage'       
#s3_req = urllib2.Request(s3_url, s3_data, { 'X-OPENTOK-AUTH': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  s3_req = urllib2.Request(s3_url, s3_data, { 'X-OPENTOK-AUTH': s3_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  s3_req.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'                                                  

try:                                                                                      
    f = urllib2.urlopen(s3_req)                                                    
except urllib2.URLError as e:                                                      
    print e.reason                                                                 
    print e.code                                                                   
    print e.read()                                                                 
    sys.exit()
```

Expected result is to have the S3-Archive set within the tokbox project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in [1], the token to do REST API requests must be in the following format:

{
    "iss": "your_api_key",
    "ist": "project",
    "iat": current_timestamp_in_seconds,
    "exp": expire_timestamp_in_seconds,
    "jti": "jwt_nonce"
}

[1] https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#authentication

Comment: Hello Jose,Thank you for your response.. In my question above, I do mention that I've tried both account and project.